# Why do cocoapod create a dummy class for every pod?

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods, cocoapods-1.0.1

Just as title described. I do not understand why does it did that?

[image]

Comment: All I can find that it is needed to build the pod, [CocoaPods Under The Hood](https://www.objc.io/issues/6-build-tools/cocoapods-under-the-hood/)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a Pod that only exists as a series of categories on Apple's classes, which means that the library you create has no actual objects inside it, which doesn't work at the linker stage of the build process. Adding a dummy file to each Pod means there's a guarantee that each library contains an object.

Answer (score 0):

you can use class-dump to get all headers, then get all dependency repo from checking headers whose pre is podsDummy.